# Sum of differentiable functions.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

True/False Question :  suppose that $f+g$ is differentiable at point $x_0$ therefore $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x_0$

I think this statement is false and I got a counter example : 
$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \,\,x>0\\
x & \,\,x<0
\end{cases};
  g(x)=\begin{cases}
x\,\, & x-1>0\\
0 & \leq0
\end{cases}$
$(f+g)(x)=\begin{cases}
x\,\, & x>0\\
x\,\, & x<0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}\rightarrow\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\,\,\left(f+g\right)(x)=x,
 \left(f+g\right)'(0)=0$

Nor $f$ or $g$ are differentiable at $x_0=0$ but the sum is differentiable.

**However second True/false question got me very confused, it says**:

suppose that $f+g$ and $f$ is differentiable at point $x_0$ therefore $g$ are differentiable at $x_0$ and here I got confused, I can not find acounter example however I can not also find a proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $(f+g)-f=g$ and that the difference of differentiable functions is differentiable.

Comment: How stupid of me ! Thank you, thread closed !(your answer will be accepted :)

Comment: another small question is it correct that if $f\cdot g$
  and$ f$
  are differentiable at $x_{0}$
  

Therefore$ g=\frac{f\cdot g}{f}$  is differentiable $\iff f(x_{0})\neq0$

Comment: @PavelPenshin First of all, great question, and even I was curious whether $$g = f*g/f$$  is differentiable. Lol its been 4 yrs so if you do know the answer now, could you help me too please.